# SQLite Android can't figure out where i went wrong

Tags: android, cursor, android-sqlite

Im writing a simple database application where you enter your name and mark using 2 edit text and press button to save the database and move to second activity where it shows the database result.
The database contain 4 columns :id ,name , mark, operations
where "operations" column is taking its result from ops where i already put its input inside the program.

i put a try and catch when inserting and it shows up a dialog to inform me that whether it is a success or not. the result is a success however the app force close when moving to view activity. here is my database class code

```
 public class DateBase {

public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "user_name";
public static final String KEY_MARK = "user_mark";
public static final String KEY_OPERATION = "operation";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Statistic";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "user_interface";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DBInterface MyInterface;
private final Context MyContext;
private SQLiteDatabase MyDB;


private static class DBInterface extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DBInterface(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_MARK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_OPERATION + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DateBase(Context c)
{
    MyContext = c;
}

public DateBase open() throws SQLException
{
    MyInterface = new DBInterface(MyContext);
    MyDB = MyInterface.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    MyInterface.close();
}

public long InsertEntry(String name, String mark, String ops) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_MARK, mark);
    cv.put(KEY_OPERATION, ops);
    return MyDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_MARK, KEY_OPERATION};
    Cursor c = MyDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iMark = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MARK);
    int iOperation = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPERATION);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iMark) + " " + c.getString(iOperation) + "\n";
    }


    return result;
}
  }
```

here is the inserting code while clickon the button:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean diditwork = true;
    try {String name = ed1.getText().toString();
    String mark = ed2.getText().toString();
    String ops = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ops.length(); i++)
    {
        switch (op[i]) // int[] op = new int[]{1,3};
        {
        case 1:
            ops = ops + "+ ";
            break;
        case 2:
            ops = ops + "- ";
            break;
        case 3:
            ops = ops + "* ";
            break;
        case 4:
            ops = ops + "/ ";
            break;
        }
    }

    DateBase entry = new DateBase(MainActivity.this);
    entry.open();
    entry.InsertEntry(name, mark, ops);
    entry.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        diditwork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog (this);
        d.setTitle("NO WAY!!");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    } finally {
        if (diditwork)
        {
            Dialog d = new Dialog (this);
            d.setTitle("Heck YA!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Success");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
    }

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(MainActivity.this, DatabaseView.class);
    startActivity(i);
     }
```

and finally here is my getting data code:
     public class DatabaseView extends Activity {

```
TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.database_view);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    DateBase info = new DateBase(this);
    info.open();
    String Data = info.getData();
    info.close();

    tv.setText(Data);
}

}
```

The exception i got on LogCAT is:

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
  ComponentInfo{com.database/com.database.DatabaseView}:       
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: user_mark: , while compiling: SELECT id, user_name, user_mark, operation FROM user_interface
```

I just cant figure out where is the problem. please help me out, sorry for my bad english

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: the answer is pretty obvious...

Comment: check the column name user_mark

Comment: check the column name user_mark if its same and still gives the exception try changing the column name

Comment: IT is the same tried to change the column name to "marks" the exception becomes: no such column: marks:...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you added this field user_mark later so the system is still using the old database try uninstalling the app and installing it again otherwise I thing everything is pretty much in place

Answer (score 1):

Yes, There is no fault in code the problem is that told by Aashish. so please clear data from Manage Application and run again.